# Как высчитать разницу времени?

Tags: java, android

Есть два времени в String, например, 10:45(ожидаемое) и 10:30(текущее). Как определить количество минут до ожидаемого значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться `LocalTime` и `ChronoUnit`, если используется Java8:

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.parse("10:30");
LocalTime expected = LocalTime.parse("10:45");
Long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(now, expected);
System.out.println(minutes); //15
```